# Update Mapbox map on page scroll trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, mapbox, fullpage.js

So I've successfully set up a mapbox instance, and then later I want to use a trigger to adjust the center point of the map; what I'm essentially trying to do is update the map from inside another function. I understand why it isn't working, I just don't know how to fix it.

```
L.mapbox.map('mapbox', 'mjchamplin.igp7fgmn', { scrollWheelZoom: false, dragging: false, center: [instaLat, instaLon], zoom: 12});
```

...the map loads great. Later on, another function (using https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js):

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({

...

    onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
    //after leaving section 1
        if(index == '1' && nextIndex == '2' && direction =='down'){
                    console.log("Going to section 2!");
                    map.centerzoom({ lat: 38.9, lon: -77.03 }, 5);

        }               
    }
});
```

Which returns this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'centerzoom' of undefined
```

So essentially, how would I pass this new information to my existing map from inside another function? Or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused as of what you are trying to do exactly. Are you trying to change the map from another page? Also if you want to change the center of the map you use.

map.setView([lat, long], zoom);